# After burning bootloader, Windows 10 doesn't recognize the USB device

Tags: usb, atmega32u4, windows

I just built my own version of an Arduino Micro, using the ATMEGA32u4 chip. I burned the bootloader to it via another Arduino (Arduino Nano from [banggood.com](https://www.banggood.com/)).

The Arduino Nano uses an ATMEGA328 chip, so it *should* work as an ISP programmer. None the less, I hooked up the Nano to my custom board, according to [Sparkfun's Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader), and proceeded to burn the bootloader. The Arduino IDE says that I have successfully burned the bootloader.

However, when I plug in the newly burned custom board, Windows 10 throws the error, saying, `USB Device Not Recognized` followed by `The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it`.

I have searched for a solution, but none seem to come up. My question is, what do I need to do in order to get this custom board working as an Arduino? Thanks!

Comment: Which bootloader did you burn?

Answer (score 2):

You need a number of things to be true before the (new) bootloader will work:

- The hardware needs to be wired correctly
- You have used an appropriate crystal as the clock
- You have installed the correct bootloader (ie. one for the Atmega32U4)
- The fuses are set to boot into the bootloader
- The fuses are set for the correct bootloader size
- The fuses are set correctly for the clock type and the clock speed (for example, don't have the "divide clock by 8" bit set)

I have a [sketch that analyses your chip signature and fuses](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) which will also report on what bootloader it detected (assuming it is one from a recognized list). You could run that and amend your question to post the resulting display from the serial monitor.

I also have a [sketch that programs a bootloader](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) for various chips including the Atmega32U4. This sketch also sets the appropriate fuses.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem. After further testing, I found that my ATMEGA32u4 from DIGIKEY was damaged. Most likely I damaged it by accident, but I can't be sure. Oh man, wouldn't it be nice if life had a CTRL+Z on it?